# Delete Node in BST (2)

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have BST and when I want to delete node from BST, nothing happened. Could someone explain why?

Here is my code:

```
private void delete(int value, Node node) {
    if (value<node.value) delete(value, node.left);
    else if (value> node.value)
        delete(value, node.right);
    else {
        if (node.left != null && node.right != null) {
            int maxFromLeft = findMax(node.left);
            node.value = maxFromLeft;
            delete(maxFromLeft, node.left);
        } else if (node.left != null) {
            Node trash = node;
            node = node.left;
            trash = null;
        } else if (node.right != null) {
            Node trash = node;
            node = node.right;
            trash = null;
        } else {
            node = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. This will help others to reproduce your bugs, and find them because sometimes bugs are hidden in other functions. For example, a simplified `Node` class and `findMax` function. It will be better if you can provide a simple test case and the error output, expected output.

Comment: It looks like you are assuming pass-by-reference semantics, which Java does not have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method with the signature `void delete(int,Node)` cannot work. Consider what happens when you try to delete the root from a tree that has only one node: this method cannot delete the node because method parameters are passed by value.

What you can do is return the modified BST from this method:

```
Node delete(int value, Node node) {
    if (value<node.value) node.left = delete(value, node.left);
    else if (value> node.value)
        node.right = delete(value, node.right);
    ...I'll leave the rest as an exercise...
    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this part

```
if (node.left != null) {
 Node trash = node;
 node = node.left;
 trash = null;
}
```

You need to delete `node`. This do nothing `node = node.left`. It just assigns one reference to another. This dosn't need too `trash = null`.

To delete node you need to disconnect it from it's parent firstly, and connect a one child of a deleted node to the parent and insert other child where it should be!